# CSR's with null bytes in them

Tags: x.509

According to wikipedia.org's article on [X.509 certificates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Exploits), "*There are implementation errors with X.509 that allow e.g. falsified subject names using null-terminated strings Marlinspike Blackhat 2009 or code injections attacks in certificates.*" My question is...  how do I create a CSR with null bytes within them?

Here's a CSR that does have one in it: `csr-with-null.pem`

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIIBSTCBtQIBADAQMQ4wDAYDVQQKDAVhYgBjZDCBnTALBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEDgY0A
MIGJAoGBALoqjrGPCxX2oWX8APXhB3dzKJAXWHKWSlMWDw1whCP+EpsdFY2pTq+D
RnX8wRIP2yssIii/4FwsDxjcjlYMpSqYBPnEq3Lql/7LeW5ulLn4wk4Gnd4B55WP
BLveMNCORZXtE5rNJISTRMHYZKp7sLOPFlE3Gb5G/o/rkxSqOKOPAgMBAAEwCwYJ
KoZIhvcNAQEFA4GBAB0CX/T2wBTHHE6dcCFwzXsVkqkoewQbLjDLoAjCBy7nFrCI
6+kLPj7zcYi6f+Jg+OcFMl0Oat+2iO7OARSib3S0WyuAFpJQQwZIiG9RISy2HF1A
jQPuWvOan1GsY74Dn0kac6BIaWlY0/9h/iIcl4BiUaFrW+xUinKGWofsdq8l
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

According to [asn1parse](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/asn1parse.php) the value corresponding to the `organizationName` has a length of 5 even though the "`abcd`" string displayed has a length of four.

```
$ cat csr-with-null.pem | openssl asn1parse -i
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 329 cons: SEQUENCE
    4:d=1  hl=3 l= 181 cons:  SEQUENCE
    7:d=2  hl=2 l=   1 prim:   INTEGER           :00
   10:d=2  hl=2 l=  16 cons:   SEQUENCE
   12:d=3  hl=2 l=  14 cons:    SET
   14:d=4  hl=2 l=  12 cons:     SEQUENCE
   16:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim:      OBJECT            :organizationName
   21:d=5  hl=2 l=   5 prim:      UTF8STRING        :abcd
   28:d=2  hl=3 l= 157 cons:   SEQUENCE
   31:d=3  hl=2 l=  11 cons:    SEQUENCE
   33:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim:     OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
   44:d=3  hl=3 l= 141 prim:    BIT STRING
  188:d=1  hl=2 l=  11 cons:  SEQUENCE
  190:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim:   OBJECT            :sha1WithRSAEncryption
  201:d=1  hl=3 l= 129 prim:  BIT STRING
```

The thing is, there's a null byte between the `ab` and the `cd`. You can see it in [an ASN1 hexdump](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MIIBSTCBtQIBADAQMQ4wDAYDVQQKDAVhYgBjZDCBnTALBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEDgY0AMIGJAoGBALoqjrGPCxX2oWX8APXhB3dzKJAXWHKWSlMWDw1whCP-EpsdFY2pTq-DRnX8wRIP2yssIii_4FwsDxjcjlYMpSqYBPnEq3Lql_7LeW5ulLn4wk4Gnd4B55WPBLveMNCORZXtE5rNJISTRMHYZKp7sLOPFlE3Gb5G_o_rkxSqOKOPAgMBAAEwCwYJKoZIhvcNAQEFA4GBAB0CX_T2wBTHHE6dcCFwzXsVkqkoewQbLjDLoAjCBy7nFrCI6-kLPj7zcYi6f-Jg-OcFMl0Oat-2iO7OARSib3S0WyuAFpJQQwZIiG9RISy2HF1AjQPuWvOan1GsY74Dn0kac6BIaWlY0_9h_iIcl4BiUaFrW-xUinKGWofsdq8l) or via `cat -vET`:

```
$ cat csr-with-null.pem | openssl asn1parse -i | cat -vET | grep ab
   21:d=5  hl=2 l=   5 prim:      UTF8STRING        :ab^@cd$
```

That CSR was generated with a library called phpseclib but I'd like to know how to generate similar CSR's with OpenSSL or some other more standardized tool.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
openssl req -new -key privkey.pem -out test.csr -subj "/O=ab\000cd"
```

That got me this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

ie. the organizationName is ab000cd - not ab\00cd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These things are normally done programmatically. The command-line apps from OpenSSL are restricted in many ways, and don't give access to the full power of the underlying library. If you look at the [source code](http://www.openssl.org/source/), you will find the implementation of the `req` command in `apps/req.c`. For subject name parsing, that command relies on the `parse_name()` function (defined in `apps/apps.c`). That function internally builds the name elements as so many null-terminated C strings, which, by definition, cannot contain a null byte. Therefore, no possible way to achieve what you seek with that tool alone.

So one option is to simply download OpenSSL's source code, patch `apps/req.c` to include a null byte where you want it, compile it and run it. This will require a bit of knowledge of C. You will want to use the [X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt()](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt.html) function (or one of its acolytes), with an explicit `len` parameter (not -1) to use as "string" a sequence of bytes which includes your null byte. If you look at `parse_name()` in `apps/apps.c`, you will see that it invokes `X509_NAME_add_entry_by_NID()` with `len` set to -1: that's the exact point that you'll want to change.

Another option is to generate a "normal" certificate request, with another letter where you would like to have your null byte (e.g. a 'Z'). Then, make sure to convert your request to binary ("DER") format; then use a binary file editor to replace the 'Z' with a byte of value 0; then recompute the signature so that it matches the new request contents. This last step can be done with basic Linux command-line tools (`dd` for file surgery, `sha1sum` to get a new hash, `dc` to do the big integer arithmetics) but you have to master both ASN.1/DER and [PKCS#1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447), and if you did then you would not have asked the question you asked.

Comment: openssl (which asker has) can (probably more easily) do the hash and signature (for RSA including ASN.1 and padding); see my answer and the asker's recap to the very similar question http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/58717/what-part-of-the-csr-is-hashed-in-order-to-create-its-signature/58735 . Also for a change this small instead of patching and recompiling openssl, you could just run it under a debugger and tweak the data at the right place.